# If the nominal interest rate on bonds becomes 10% and the historical average return of stocks in the US is 10% why would you ever invest in stocks?

Tags: investing, bonds

It seems like given the lower volatility of bonds and the prospect of equivalent return, bonds are the better deal. Am I missing something?

Comment: "the historical average return of stocks in the US is 10%" — That figure is (a) nominal, and (b) historical. What does the future look like?

Comment: Will the bond rates **STAY** at 10% for many, many years?  If so, *why*?  How high is inflation, and what will that do to the stock market?

Comment: Bottom line: these things don’t happen in a vacuum.

Comment: @Flux Bond yields are also nominal so your point (a) seems moot.

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing the past with the expected future. Yes, *historically* stocks have averaged around 10% growth, but that is an average over a long period of time, and there is massive fluctuation around that. Gains(losses) have been anywhere between 40% and -30% in a year, with less variance as you look at longer periods.

But if bond yields go to 10% at any given time, that would put huge downward pressure on stock prices for various reasons. As stock prices go down, their *expected* return in the future goes up (you're "buying cheap"). Stocks will always have higher *expected* returns than bonds just due to their risky nature.

So it's still a tradeoff of risk/return - as you take more risk, you can expect higher returns on average. I don't think you'll ever find a time where you can expect 10% guaranteed return from bond and 10% return from risky equities. If you're satisfied with 10% safe return, that's fine, but you will likely see higher returns in equities, so there will be an opportunity cost.

Answer (score 2):

10% is unusually high for bonds, and it's not likely to stay that high for long. Unless you include high risk "junk bonds".

10% on shares is more common if you combine growth and dividends. And if inflation remains high without the economy crashing, then shares might go up faster than that.

Answer (score 1):

If interest rates drop, then borrowers will issue new bonds ASAP at the lower rate, in order to redeem the high-rate bonds.

Falling rates are also likely to stimulate growth, which means the stock market would grow.

Comment: But what if the 10% rate is on long-term non-callable bonds such as 10-to-30-year Treasurys, as it was in the 1980s?

Comment: @nanoman in that case, by all means buy them. (I remember people buying 15% 5- and 7-year CDs at "peak interest rate".  It's part of what lead to the S&L collapse.) Note, though, that by definition you'd only be able to invest the money you have **at that time**.  Would you have to get that money by selling stocks at a loss?  And of course you'd have to decide where all investments *after* that have to go.